# Undefined behaviour during evaluation of a potential constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

extern int i;

struct S {
    S() {
        if (i == 0) {
            puts("Hello, world!");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
};

S s;

int i = 1 + 2 * INT_MIN;

int main() { }
```

As I understood the evaluation of expressions, this is a strictly conforming program, that prints "Hello, world!", then exits, and never actually evaluates the initialiser for `i`:

> **3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.init]**
>
> [...]
>
> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.
>
> Constant initialization is performed:
>
> -- [...]
>
> -- if an object with static or thread storage duration is not initialized by a constructor call and if every full-expression that appears in its initializer is a constant expression.
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called *static initialization*; all other initialization is *dynamic initialization*. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place. Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is either ordered or unordered. [...] Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their definitions in the translation unit. [...]
>
> **5.19 Constant expressions [expr.const]**
>
> A conditional-expression is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the
>   following as a potentially evaluated subexpression (3.2) [...]:
>
> -- [...]
>
> -- a result that is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type;
>
> [...]
>
> A *literal constant expression* is a prvalue core constant expression of literal type, but not pointer type. [...] Collectively, literal constant expressions, reference constant expressions, and address constant expressions are called *constant expressions*.

Because the expression `1 + 2 * INT_MIN` has signed integer overflow, it is not a core constant expression, thus not a literal constant expression, thus not a constant expression. Because the initialiser for `i` is not a constant expression, dynamic initialisation is performed. The initialisation for `s` is also dynamic, and because its definition precedes that of `i`, its constructor runs first. At that point, only zero-initialisation has been performed, so the check `i == 0` should evaluate as true.

However, GCC and clang agree that `i` can be statically initialised to `1`. My experience when those two agree is that they are correct, so I am left wondering... is any part of my analysis incorrect?

Comment: Ah, well that's weird since the compiler can do the arithmetic at compile time..? Weird question, +1.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to evaluate the expression `1 + 2 * INT_MIN` in order to find that it invokes signed integer overflow? (And therefore already have UB?)

Comment: I don't think it is the constant expression (or lack thereof) that is the cause of your issue.  It appears it is treating it like it would an uninitialized variable, which would appear to make sense since `extern` just tells the compiler that the variable is declared somewhere, and your initialization hasn't happened yet.  This would mean that `i` is some random bits in memory, so you have better odds of winning the lottery than it being 0, and thus exiting the program as you expect.

Comment: Isn't that similar to the example in [basic.start.init]/3? I.e. couldn't `i` be initialized statically even though it isn't required?

Comment: Very strange. If I make it not a core constant expression another way (for example, by calling a non-`constexpr` function), then it prints "Hello, world!". Appears to be a bug with both compilers.

Comment: I would expect `int i = LLONG_MAX;` to also make it print "Hello, World" (when `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long long)`), but it doesn't. Seems like the compilers just ignore that rule.

Comment: +1, I'll join the party. Couldn't this be because of 3.6.2/3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that `1 + 2 * INT_MIN` *is* evaluated at compile-time, and `i` *is* initialized during static-initialization. This is allowed in [basic.start.init]/3

> An implementation is permitted to perform the initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration as a static initialization even if such initialization is not required to be done statically, provided
>   that
>
> - the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value of any other object of namespace
>     scope prior to its initialization, and
> - the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be
>     produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were
>     initialized dynamically.

So, even though `i` isn't required to be initialized during constant initialization, it *can* be initialized during static initialization, which is still before dynamic initialization. The same could be true for `s`, but I don't think that's possible for a compiler to do because of the side-effects.

---

As [sftrabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150634/sftrabbit) noted, instead of invoking UB, you can make the initializing expression arbitrarily complex, so that `i` is indeed only initialized during dynamic initialization. For example:

```
int foobar()
{
    return 42;
}

int i = foobar();
```

prints `Hello, world!` on both compilers.

---

As a side remark: In order to see that `1 + 2 * INT_MIN` invokes UB because of signed integer overflow, it might be necessary to evaluate the expression. This could lead to UB during the initialization.

Comment: Also, IIRC UB can be retroactive, which means that in a program execution that contains UB (and the evaluation of `1 + 2 * INT_MIN`, which is sooner or later going to be performed with 100% certainty, does invoke UB), UB itself may manifest *before* the execution of the particular instruction that contains UB. In other words, the OP's expectation that `At that point, only zero-initialisation has been performed, so the check i == 0 should evaluate as true` is incorrect.

Comment: DyP: Thanks, that's exactly what I missed. @AndyProwl I understand that, but *only* if the evaluation actually takes place. I had a call to `exit` to prevent that from happening. `if (0 && 1 / 0)` is a well-known example that has many times been explicitly said to have defined behaviour, because `1 / 0` is never evaluated.

Comment: @hvd: Whoops I totally missed the call to `exit()` here. Forgive me, I should rather go have a NYE party :)

Comment: Good idea, and something I'll be doing shortly too. :)

Comment: Wait. Since it has UB when evaluated, how does the implemenration know that the "provided that" conditions apply in order to know the static initialization optimization is valid?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think that's a good point. As I understand it, the initialization *must not* be done as constant initialization, that would be ill-formed. So it is dynamic initialization and the UB happens when the expression is evaluated. The implementation could specify a behaviour for the evaluation of this expression, and according to this specification, it can check if the rules for static init apply. That is, as I tried to point out in the side remark, I think this relies on UB, but is not ill-formed. Oh, and a happy new year :D

Comment: If code which ran before the initialization had said "if (should_launch_missiles) { launch_missiles(); exit(1); }"` should a good compiler elide the "should_launch_missiles" check if the it would be impossible to avoid Undefined Behavior when `should_launch_missiles` is false?

Comment: @supercat I think that's a different question that is better not answered within a comment.